# RxJS mergeScan vs scan

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am learning RxJS and I can't figure out the difference between scan and mergeScan of the RxJS. Both examples:

```
const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const one$ = click$.pipe(mapTo(1));
const seed = 0;
const count$ = one$.pipe(
  mergeScan((acc, one) => of(acc + one), seed),
);
count$.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

... and

```
const click$ = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const one$ = click$.pipe(mapTo(1));
const seed = 0;
const count$ = one$.pipe(scan((acc, one) => (acc + one), seed));
count$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

... produce the same results (number of mouse clicks) - so what is the difference? Are they both needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mergeScan` can execute observable inside but `scan` cannot, a typical use case would be something like inifite scroll that you want to call the endpoint continuously

```
const click$ = fromEvent(loadmore, 'click');
const count$ = click$.pipe(
  mergeScan((acc, one) => httpGetPage(acc.pageCusor+1).pipe(map(res=>{
    return {pageCusor:pageCusor++,contet.concat(res)}
})), {pageCursor:0,content:[]}),
);
```

To examine, you can try console.log in your `scan` example and try return a `of(value)`, it will show `Observable`

```
const count$ = one$.pipe(scan((acc, one) => of(acc + one), seed));
count$.subscribe((x) => console.log(x));
```

Comment: So in the example I provided it is the `of` operator that I wouldn't be able to call from inside the `scan` operator, but I can call it from inside `mergeScan`, is it?

Comment: of(something) is an observable, if you just want to return a plain value and when the wrapping operator function expect an observable as a return value, you can then use of()

Answer (score 0):

As documentation says

> It's like scan, but the Observables returned by the accumulator are
> merged into the outer Observable.

accumulator function return type of `mergeScan` should be `ObservableInput`

`mergeScan` 1st performs the `scan` operation and then subscribe to inner observable which is returned by accumulator function and store it `acc` and emits the same.

if you replace mergeScan` with scan in this line and log like below

```
scan((acc, one) => {
    console.log("acc ",acc);
    return of(acc + one);
  }, seed),
```

you will see `acc` value storing as an `Observable`.Log will be like this
`acc Observable {_subscribe: ƒ}`

But if you use `maergeScan` we will see the log like `acc  1`

So moral of the story is,if your accumulator function returns observable the you have to use `mergeScan` otherwise `scan` will be fine